# how to redirect back to before page

Tags: php

i found this link
[Redirect with Timer in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1901796/redirect-with-timer-in-php)

i already try this

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://yourdomain.com"/>


<?php

// wait 5 seconds and redirect :)
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5;url=http://yourdomain.com\"/>";

?>
```

Its work but i want redirect back to previous page, any idea? the algorithm is i change page after 5 seconds and want back at previous page after 5 sec to and continue back..
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 4):

Use HTTP_REFERER which will give you the page from where you came to the current page.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

```
<?php

// wait 5 seconds and redirect :)
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5;url=".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."\"/>";

?>
```

Comment: sorry btw i didnt notice i just link in a one website which it only change the index.php?page=1 to index.php?page=2 and i wanna back change the ?page=2 to ?page=1 and continue again. So i put the code(php redirect) in one file is index.php, and the problem is i have 2 argument in 1 file index if i add the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Answer (score 1):

use `window.go(-1);`

for details help see http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp

Answer (score 1):

Can Be done with Pure javascript

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.history.back()
}, 5000);
```

OR if you want to use php

```
setTimeout(function(){
  window.location = '<?=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ?>'
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try redirecting to

```
sleep(5);
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

Comment: i dont know that scripts must be placed, sorry i didnt notice i'm redirect in a 1 website, mydomain?page=1 and mydomain?page=2